# Uniqueness of Ax=b

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following A:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
-1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
-1  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   2
```

and the following b:

```
    -13.2631
    -6.3221
    -16.5563

My fortran algorithm gives the solution as:

-2.726376124
0
1.744365734
-4.040076979
-7.629776969
-10.63492292
-6.197426942
-5.151330008
-1.982803066
-7.065673058
```

Now, if I change the columns of A as the following,

```
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
-1  0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
-1  0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

I need to get the same solution except the rows of the solution should shift. However, I get the following:

```
-2.726376124
0
1.744365734
-7
-4.040076979
-7.629776969
-10.63492292
-6.2631
-2.048476124
-5.282676124
```

For example, instead of getting -6.197426942, I get -6.2631. Weirdly, MATLAB gives me a unique solution but it doesn't match neither of my solutions. If you do Ax=b, both of these multiplications match the specified b, so there is no numerical error. The rank of A is 3 so I guess does that mean the solution should be unique? Could you please help me out? Is the solution supposed to be unique? If so, why am I getting two different solutions? If the solution is not supposed to be unique, why?

Comment: sorry just corrected.

Comment: How do you compute your solution?

Comment: Well, I did not write the codes but there two functions.

Comment: The first function does the following:c* Function: generates the lu factors for an n X n matrix
c*           with scaled column pivoting or without pivoting
c*
c* This routine produces a factorization
c* aj = (I-L)*U where L is strictly lower triangular
c* and U is non-strictly upper triangular. U is
c* returned in the diagonal and upper right triangle of aj;
c* L is returned in the lower left triangle of aj. The second function does the folliwng: 
c* Subroutine to solve an n X n linear system by forward/backward
c* substitution, using LU factors generated by GNLUSQ.

Comment: Independent of the solver, both solutions seem to be correct because when I do A1*x1 = A2* x2 = b.

Comment: Ok I figured that there are 3 equations and 10 unknowns, so the solution is not supposed to be unique. In reality, I know the first 7 elements of the x vector. Therefore, I need to construct the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions to $Ax = b$ are not unique. $A$ is a 3x10 matrix and has rank 3 (as you already said). This means that the kernel (or null space) of $A$, that is the set $K = \{x | Ax = 0 \}$, has dimension 7. Moreover, since the rank of $A$ is the number of rows of $A$, there are solutions $x$ for any given $b$. Say, for a given $b_0$, you find a solution $x_0$ such that $Ax_0 = b_0$. Then the complete set of solutions of $Ax = b_0$ is $x_0 + K$. Since K is nonzero, there are several solutions.